# Conditionally update item or delete item in one query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, what I'm trying to achieve here is two things. First one is to decrement the quantity of a product. Second is that if that product quantity is 0 then delete that product.
So I'm trying to set a condition that if product quantity is 0 then delete that product otherwise simply decrement the quantity.

Here is my cart document:

[image]

And here is my function:

```
const cart = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userID: req.body.userID, "items.productID": req.body.productID },
    {$lt: ['items.productID', 0] ? { $pull: { items: { productID: req.body.productID } } } : { $inc: { 'items.$.quantity': -1 } }},
    { new: true }
);
```

I have tried to achieve that with ternary operator but it didn't worked. Can anybody help me with this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a ternary operator in your query. Not only is this not supported in MongoDB, it will also simply be evaluated by node.js, not by MongoDB itself. In fact, conditional update operations of the nature you're describing are themselves not something that MongoDB is capable of handling.

Your best bet is to perform two queries, where the first one performs the decrement operation and the second pulls any items out that have a quantity less than or equal to 0:

```
const cartAfterDecrement = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userID: req.body.userID, "items.productID": req.body.productID },
    { $inc: { 'items.$.quantity': -1 } },
    { new: true }
);

const cartAfterPull = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userID: req.body.userID, items: { $elemMatch: {
        productID: req.body.productID,
        quantity: { $lte: 0 }
    } } },
    { $pull: {items: { quantity: { $lte: 0 } } } },
    { new: true }
);

const cart = cartAfterPull ? cartAfterPull : cartAfterDecrement;
```

If you wish to allow products with quantities equal to 0, then modifying the second query is a trivial matter.

The only downside to this approach is that there will be a natural, very slight delay between these two updates, which may result in a very rare case of a race condition occurring where a cart is returned and contains an item with a quantity less than or equal to 0. In order to avoid this, you will need to either filter these values out with server code or by retrieving your cart(s) using aggregation, or you will need to make use of transactions to ensure that the two operations occur in sequence without the document being retrieved between the two write operations.

With that said, constructing the appropriate array filtering logic or transaction management is beyond the scope of this question, so will not be included in this answer.

Comment: Just to give my two cents: transactions do not prevent race conditions, it only provides atomicity. Depending on the traffic his website gets, race conditions might be normal. Locking would be a suggestion for concurrency handling.

Comment: @BrunoFarias I could be mistaken, but wouldn't MongoDB's document-level write locks, combined with the singular transaction commit and MongoDB's concurrency optimization, ensure that these write operations are performed in sequence without a read between them to optimize query throughput? If not, then I would happily accept a modification to my answer to reflect best practices for avoiding such a race condition.

Comment: They would indeed be executed in sequence, but in case there was a second query, the value read by the first operation depends on the isolation level used. More on the topic here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/  .. Nevertheless, I think your answer is all good, just wanted to chime in, in case the OP believes concurrency may be an issue.

Comment: Thanks @B.Fleming for your answer and I did a little changeover to that in a way so I have only one query to run. Thanks for showing the way also I'm accepting your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Query

- you can do it with a pipeline update ( >= MongoDB 4.2)
- find the user that has that productID
- reduce the items, to an array with item but

  - if productID not the one i look for, keep it as it is
  - else if `quantity=0` remove it(don't add it to the reduced array)
  - else keep it with `quantity-1`

*[findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) accepts pipeline also, for nodejs driver you must find the method that wraps this command, or run the command directly

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70480328-m)

```js
update(
{"userID": req.body.userID,
 "items.productID": req.body.productID},
[{"$set":
  {"items":
   {"$reduce":
    {"input":"$items",
     "initialValue":[],
     "in":
     {"$switch":
      {"branches":
       [{"case":{"$ne":["$$this.productID", req.body.productID]},
         "then":{"$concatArrays":["$$value", ["$$this"]]}},
        {"case":{"$gt":["$$this.quantity", 0]},
         "then":
         {"$concatArrays":
          ["$$value",
           [{"$mergeObjects":
             ["$$this", {"$subtract":["$this.quantity", 1]}]}]]}}],
       "default":"$$value"}}}}}}])
```

Comment: Even though this might resolve the OPs question, this is extremely unreadable and would take anyone who's not well versed with mongo's QL several minutes to reason about it.

Comment: its very simple actually, just JSON syntax makes it look more complicated, if you click on the Test code here you will see the cMQL version that i wrote, code is simple. We cant do anything about it, MQL has JSON syntax, i use cMQL to escape it.

Comment: Thanks @Takis_ for your answer but I think that it is too complex for someone like me who doesn't know about what MQL and cMQL is.

Comment: @MohitPandey this is the aggregation framework, it's like the most important part of MongoDB. Its not some exotic solution. If you want to use MongoDB for more complex things you will to have to learn it anyways. You can see the course in MongoDB university its free videos it can help alot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @B. Fleming and all others for your answer. I have just use a simple code implementation for that however it wasn't what I was expected but still it's good to go.

```
    module.exports.deleteCartItem = async (req, res, next) => {
    var condition;
    var update;
    const product = await Cart.findOne({ userID: req.body.userID,
        items: { 
            $elemMatch: {
                productID: req.body.productID,
                quantity: { $lte: 0 }
            }
        } 
    });
// IF PRODUCT WITH 0 QUANTITY PULL/DELETE THAT PRODUCT
    if (product !== null) {
        condition = { userID: req.body.userID, items: { $elemMatch: { productID: req.body.productID, quantity: { $lte: 0 } } } },
        update = { $pull: {items: { quantity: { $lte: 0 } } } }
    } 
// OTHERWISE DECREMENT THE QUANTITY FOR THAT PRODUCT
else {
        condition =  { userID: req.body.userID, "items.productID": req.body.productID }
        update = { $inc: { 'items.$.quantity': -1 } }
    }
    try {
        const cart = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate(condition, update, { new: true });
        if (cart !== null) {
            res.status(200).json({
                statusCode: 1,
                message: "Item Removed",
                responseData: cart
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                statusCode: 0,
                msgCode: 462,
                message: 'Not found',
                responseData: null
            });
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Server Error: ', err);
        next(new Error('Server Error, Something was wrong!'));
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).